# Somethings wrong with my Meteor Geolocation functions

Tags: javascript, meteor, geolocation

Im unable to save the lat and lng of my coordinates. Im testing on a web browser so the coordinates should be available.

1. Im testing on a web browser, have tried other websites and no issues getting lat and lng of my position
2. The lat and lng appears on the html from `{{loc.lat}}` and `{{loc.lng}}`
3. when I type `console.log(Geolocation.latLng());`, it returns the correct current lat and lng: `Object {lat: xxx, lng: xxx};` and then a second line that shows `undefined` but its not clickable.
4. On submit of the message, error shows up on command prompt `Exception while invoking method 'postInsert' MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?` and field shows `loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ null, null ] }`. I have checked that the order is correct as well.
5. Occasionally it returns this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null` which I am unable to track since theres no mention of the problematic lines. It probably means `loc` is null?

Could someone help me on this? Thank you in advance :)

**The below is my lines for the geolocation**

In submit.js in client

```
    Template.postSubmit.onCreated(function() {
      this.interval = Meteor.setInterval(function (){
        var location = Geolocation.latLng();
        if(location) {
          Session.set('location', location);
        };
      }, 2000);    
      Session.set('postSubmitErrors', {});
    });

    Template.postSubmit.helpers({
      'loc': function () {
          return Session.get('location');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution. 
Problem lies with the structure of the loc in template.

`coordinates: [loc.lat, loc.lng]`
should be 
`coordinates: [loc.lng, loc.lat]`, as per Mongo's docs.

Answer (score 4):

`Geolocation.latLng()` triggers a refresh of the location but it is asynchronous, so it may return undefined at the beginning and then the coordinates a little later. 
As there is no asynchronous callback in the mdg:geolocation package I am using a tracker to "wait" for the result of `Geolocation.latLng()`:

```
var userGeoLocation = new ReactiveVar(null);

Tracker.autorun(function (computation) {
  userGeoLocation.set(Geolocation.latLng());
  if (userGeoLocation.get()) {
    //stop the tracker if we got something
    computation.stop();
  }
});
```

Comment: for the loading screen, just create a helper checking for the value of the reactivevar, if it's false, show a loading animation for example. for the error could you update your post with the new code ?

Comment: ok, but each time you call `Geolocation.latLng()` you have to wait, so the best thing to do is to use the tracker in your `onCreated()` callback to save the value in a reactive variable or session var like you did, and then only use this session var. Because if you call `Geolocation.latLng()` again in the event there is no guarantee that you will get something

Comment: could you provide the code where you actually call your postInsert method ?

Comment: yeah ,the Meteor.call, is missing in your event, and the Collection.insert in your method also

Comment: could you also add the rest of the method postInsert with the insertion in the database? the problem seems to come from there

Comment: location seems to have the right format, did you replace var loc = Geolocation.latLng(); in your method by a reference to the session variable, as I explained ?